# Understanding the memory ordering for C++ atomics in a single thread

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

According to the point 1.10.19 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf, the compiler cannot reorder the atomic operations on same object even in the relaxed ordering.
Below is my understanding on the memory ordering (considering only single thread):

1. Incase of **memory_order_seq_cst** the atomic operations irrespective on any object cannot be reordered.
2. Incase on **memory_order_release**/**memory_order_acquire**, as stated above the atomic operations on same object cannot be reordered.

My question is about the ordering of the Atomic operations on different objects in case of acquire/release ordering?

Question can be better understood from  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4 starting at 42:30.

Now in case of operations on same object as stated in the draft they cannot be reordered hence "SC Acq/Rel" is followed, but what about operations on different objects? Can the condition mentioned in "Plain Acq/Rel" in the video happen in this case i.e. acquire of one object be reordered above the release of other?

Comment: Yes, acq/rel are weaker than seq_cst, only imposing *some* ordering restrictions / guarantees.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ has a nice diagram.

Comment: This would mean that the mutex lock on one object(A) followed by its mutex unlock which is followed by mutex lock and unlock on other object(B) can be reordered to become mutex lock (A), mutex lock (B), mutex unlock(A), mutex ulock(B). Given mutex lock/unlock uses acquire/release barrier?

Comment: That's correct, the standard allows stuff to appear to be inside a critical section, including part of another critical section.  Practical implementations often end up with stronger ordering, given that taking a lock requires an atomic RMW, not just an acquire load.  In asm for real ISAs / real hardware, doing an atomic RMW with at least acquire semantics can't reorder as freely as a simple load.

Comment: Of course, this isn't allowed to lead to a deadlock or anything; all other parts of the as-if rule apply.  Remember this is about the rules for other threads *observing* the actions of this thread.  Not introducing possible deadlocks or whatever may limit compile-time reordering even if it doesn't require a compiler to insert extra barrier insns.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for the explanation

Comment: The std semantic is *not* specified in term of reordering ops on atomic objects. In practice, a lot of stuff can be explained in term of reordering of ops but not every aspect of the semantic.